# Laravel where model query

Tags: php, laravel-5

According to the documentaion[http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models] `all` and `get` methods retrieve results as an instance of Collection, which can be iterate through like

```
foreach ($flights as $flight) {
   echo $flight->name;
}
```

In my case only `all` method is returning instance of collection,not the `get` method because I can't iterate through result as above way and throws error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name` . If I only echo `$flight` then it prints `[{"id":3,"name":"KingFisher","created_at":"2015-09-01 16:09:09","updated_at":"2015-09-01 16:09:09"}]`, which is a json format.From this[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/convert-json-to-eloquent-collection] page I tried  `json_decode($flights, true);`and `new \Illuminate\Support\Collection(json_decode($flights, true))` but both returning same json format and I can't iterate through them as collection. Any idea?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, there is a double comma before `"created_at"`, which qualifies it as invalid. You might want to check the source of the JSON.

Comment: sorry, that's typing mistake, edited

Comment: You're sure the parsed json of `$flights` is an array? Dump it with `var_dump()`.

Comment: `var_dump()` giving me this output:                                                            object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[148]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(App\Flights)[149]
          public 'table' => string 'flights' (length=7)
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)

Comment: Looks like flight is an array. try----  $flight[0]->name

Comment: @user4621032 No, it's not an array, it's an object of the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

Comment: @ user4621032 that's working though.

Comment: So what is conclusion,`get` method returns `object` or `json` or `array`?

Comment: 'get' returns --- collection, get()->toArray() returns-- array, 'first' returns -- object

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma in your json which causes a syntax error, you can see that by using `echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: This is not an answer and should've been a comment.